# Is there an analogue of this function in Python standard modules?

Tags: python, exception, standard-library

I'm looking for a standard function (operator, decorator) that would be equivalent to the following hand-written function:

```
def defaulted(func, defaultVal):
   try:
      result = func()
   except: 
      result = defaultVal

   return result
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you realize that [`except:` is often evil](http://docs.python.org/howto/doanddont.html#except)? You propably don't want such a function to swallow syntax errors...

Comment: @delnan: Please stop perpetuating the myth that except: blocks SyntaxErrors. Unless you're dynamically compiling code (or first importing a module within that block, which is the same thing), it doesn't. It blocks enough real concerns that we don't need to resort to hyperbole about how bad it is.

Comment: @Joe: D'oh! Of course it doesn't swallow SyntaxError, sorry for the misinformation.

Comment: Although it doesn't swallow SyntaxErrors, it does swallow KeyboardInterrupt and SystemExit, neither of which one usually wants to catch.

Comment: (Other than the bare `except`) What's wrong with the code as posted?  It seems quite nice to me.  What don't you like about it?

Comment: @S.Lott: I'm actually quite new to Python, so I thought that a simple tool like this ought to be in the library and didn't want to reinvent the wheel;)

Comment: @all: Thanks for pointing out about except: evilness. I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: @Alex Jenter: What you're looking at is not "simple".  The set of exceptions to be handled and the computation of the default are anything but simple.  It's profound and important and isn't the kind of thing that really can be simplified in general.  That's why I'm asking what's wrong with what you're showing?  What don't you like about it?

Comment: @S.Lott: I don't like that it forces me to create my own "ready-for-reuse-utilities" module while I wanted to get by with a single module. Of course I could leave it all in one module, but I won't get the same satisfaction from it. Also this code doesn't allow func to have arguments - the decorator approach is better in this regard.

Comment: @Alex Jenter: You've pointed out good reasons why this function is not a good candidate for a "ready-for-reuse-utilities".  It seems like you've also pointed out a reason why there's nothing like it in the library.  What you don't like about the function is easily fixed by not writing a function in the first place.  The function doesn't seem to be helpful.  Perhaps your real question is "Why isn't this function a good idea?"  Or something along those lines.

Comment: @S.Lott: I actually needed a function that would return a file's size as a string, and a '?' in case there was some error. Of course I could have put try-except into the function directly, but the way I see it, this is an instance of a more general pattern "on error use this default", and the more try-excepts I can push down to library code, the better. I really think that such decorator would be useful in the standard library.

Comment: @Alex Jenter: "this is an instance of a more general pattern ".  True.  But not all design patterns are good candidates for library functions.  In this case, there are too many variations on the theme.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing like that in the stdlib (to the best of my knowledge). For one thing, it's bad practice: you should *never* use a bare `except`. (Instead, specify the exceptions you want to catch; that way, you won't catch everything!)

Here's a decorator:

```
>>> def defaultval(error, value):
...     def decorator(func):
...             def defaulted(*args, **kwargs):
...                     try:
...                             return func(*args, **kwargs)
...                     except error:
...                             return value
...             return defaulted
...     return decorator
...
>>> @defaultval(NameError, "undefined")
... def get_var():
...     return name
...
>>> get_var()
'undefined'
```

Answer (score 3):

No. Python's philosophy is that explicit is better than implicit. Most Python functions that are *expected* to throw exceptions regularly, like dict.__getitem__, provide equivalent versions that return a default value, like dict.get.

I've used the new with contexts for something like this before; the code looked like:

```
with ignoring(IOError, OSError):
    # some non-critical file operations
```

But I didn't need to return anything either. Generally, the whole-function level is a bad place for this, and by using decorators you'd block any chance at actually getting the error should you want to handle it more gracefully elsewhere.

Also, `except:` is extremely dangerous; you probably mean (at least) `except Exception:`, and probably something even more tightly scoped, like IOError or KeyError. Otherwise you will also catch things like Ctrl-C, SystemExit, and misspelled variable names.